# escaping &quot; from array jquery

Tags: jquery, arrays, escaping

I have array like `[&quot;'address' is required&quot;, &quot;'name-of-ceo' is required&quot;]` when i loop through this array i am getting each letter. This may be happening due to `&quot;`. Is there any way I can escape it and get `["'address' is required", "'name-of-ceo' is required"]`?

Comment: Do you actually have a String? `[&quot;...` would not be a valid Array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check this ,

```
 var myArray="[&quot;'address' is required&quot;, &quot;'name-of-ceo' is required&quot;]";
    myArray=myArray.replace(/&quot;/gi,"\"");
    myArray=myArray.replace(/\[/gi,"");
    myArray=myArray.replace(/\]/gi,"");
    myArray=myArray.split(',');

    alert(myArray);
```

Answer (score 3):

It is better to find out who is making such a thing like

```
[&quot;'address' is required&quot;, &quot;'name-of-ceo' is required&quot;]
```

Rather fixing the faulted stuff.

I am positive that it is better to fix the source.

Comment: agree.. need to fix the source(bang)

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace **&quot;**'s with **"** in place where you forming this array. On the server side, I think. This is not a javascript issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
var string = "[&quot;'address' is required&quot;, &quot;'name-of-ceo' is required&quot;]";

string = string.replace(/&quot;/g, '"');
```

If you want to parse this string into a Javascript object, You can use Douglas Crockford's JSON functions which can be downloaded from [github here](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js).

So, download json2.js from the above github page. Include it in your page like this:

```
<script src="json2.js"></script>
```

and then parse your JSON string using:

```
var myJsonObject = JSON.parse(string);
```